# Cloning a git repository

Tags: git

This is my first time using any source control so I am a bit confused. When cloning a repository for the first time, am I going to clone to the destination of any folder that I want or will this destination folder need to be in my workspace for eclipse(where the code is)? Sorry for the newb question. I couldn't find anything on it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone a git repository to any location you want. I don't have direct experience with Eclipse, but I imagine if you're cloning an existent Eclipse project, you can simply open it in Eclipse by navigating to the location where you cloned the repository and adding it to your Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your response HBHB, so help me understand here please. The repository is only the clone of the branch that you are pulling from, if you want to make any changes can you manually change the contents of the file from your local repository? Is this an effiecent way to make a change?

Comment: No problem @scerrecrow. What else would you like me to explain?

Comment: I edited my post above. The project isn't necessarily an eclipse project, I am just using eclipse for the source editing.

Comment: I don't see what has changed in your question. But, if this is not an Eclipse project, don't worry about it. Just clone the repository anywhere you like on your computer and work from there. Some people keep their code in one place. Others may have multiple clients, so will keep each client's repository in a repository with the client name. Just place it somewhere on your computer that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit depending on the OS you are using and how happy you are with a  command line input shell.

### Windows solution

If on Windows and want to click-and-run solution you could add an entry to explorer context (right mouse click) on directories with [this registry entry](https://gist.github.com/kingma-sbw/69d8bab940ec2b87a578ae404abbefe8):

```ini
; registry entry for rmc "Clone here"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git-clone]
@="Clone here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git-clone\command]
@="Powershell -NoProfile -Command \"Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V' ; git clone $(Get-Clipboard)\""
```

First copy the url to any repo than right click on a folder and select `Clone here`. It will create the clone in a new folder with the same name as the repo. Rename this folder at you discretion.